# Anybody know how to create the filters to filter the content using views?

Tags: views

Here my critical question is how to create filters in a menu which is having some child

filters too. Filters are taken from views based on (Year,and in child - dates,and in

sub-child - category's which we provide in taxonomy),so that while selecting the particular

fields in the child filters ,the result of contents should display. the filters should not be

a select list ,dropdown,or auto compete field.It should shown in a menu and filters are in

its child menu one by one.

anyone know how to do this Kindly reply for this shortly .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating any filter in views then see the query string in the address bar. It gives you array.
You can use these query strings to create your custom menu links.
Use "AND", "OR" operators in filters.
Then do little custom code.
Also use $_GET to get filter values from filters.

Comment: Thanks rishi and Duncanmoo ,

i have created categories using taxonomy and filtered the content in views using taxonomy term id.

Then i displayed the taxonomy exposed filters as menu .and did some custom code to show the menu as parent and child.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your view path is `dhinesh/news` and you have a contextual filter for year, the URL will be `dhinesh/news/2012` for 2012 filtered news.

Then go to your menu and add the filter menu items in (you can also pragmatically create the menu items, but that is another question)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks rishi and Duncanmoo ,

i have created categories using taxonomy and filtered the content in views using taxonomy term id.

Then i displayed the taxonomy exposed filters as menu .and did some custom code to show the menu as parent and child.

Comment: Dhinesh, could you be more specific about what solved your problem, so future readers of this question could benefit from what you learned?